# Progress bar not animating properly after pausing and resetting mid animation

Tags: ios, swift

I have a progress bar that animates from 0-1.0 continuously. I set it to 0 if the user pauses the app. The problem is if they resume quickly the progress bar doesn't go to 1.0 like it should.

I know (well am pretty sure) it's an issue with a doubling of the animation.

- I have the progress bar going from 0 - 1 in 15 seconds
- I pause
- I set the progress bar to 0 and remove all animations
- I resume right away
- The progress no longer fills the bar on subsequent animations

  If I wait > 15s to resume there is no issue.

---

Here is the code that animates my progress bar.

```
    self.progressBar.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    self.progressBar.progress = 0.0
    self.progressBar.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.progressBar.layer.removeAllAnimations()

    self.progressBar.progress = 1.0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: time) {
        self.progressBar.layoutIfNeeded()

    }
```

I go from 0 - 1.0 progress continuously and I was having issues with the completion block not going to 0 in time. (That's why it resets before it animates)

If the user pauses it:

```
    self.progressBar.progress = 0.0
    self.progressBar.layoutIfNeeded()
    progressBar.layer.removeAllAnimations()
```

Then when I go to resume the progress bar doesn't get to 1.0 progress. It continuously increases the amount each time the func is run until after about 5 cycles.

While researching this issue I came across a SO post about using CATransaction to reset the progress bar to 0 upon completion but that caused the issue with the second, fourth, etc cycles not animating because of the speed I call it.

This issue presents itself when you try to set progress to both 0 and 1 at the same time. However, I'm not doing that here as far as I can tell. It works 100% except in this pause/resume scenario.

I am 99% sure its a doubling of progress animations but I'm not sure how that's possible when I am removing the animations before animating it.

Note: Using progressBar.setProgress doesn't change anything.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of setting the progress to 0, try setting it to the current value of the progress bar. Also, try it without removing the animations when the user pauses.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all animations from progressView you can use this approach:

```
for (CALayer *layer in self.progressView.layer.sublayers) {
    [layer removeAllAnimations];
}
```